# Как связать модели и сессии в django?

Tags: django

У меня есть 3 модели: Еда, Прием пищи, и связующий класс Прием пищи + еда. Не могу понять как использовать сессии с этими моделями. Необходимо создавать эти модели на определенный период времени с помощью сессий.

models.py:

```
class Food(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название')
bel = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Белки')
jir = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Жиры')
ugl = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Углеводы')
cal = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Калории')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Еда'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Название приема пищи')
    time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Время приема', blank=False)
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food, through='Racion', through_fields=('meal', 'food'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Racion(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gramm = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Грамм')
    def bel(self):
        b = (self.gramm/100)*self.food.bel
        return b
    def jir(self):
        j = (self.gramm/100)*self.food.jir
        return j
    def ugl(self):
        u = (self.gramm/100)*self.food.ugl
        return u
    def cal(self):
        c = (self.gramm/100)*self.food.cal
        return c
```

Comment: Лучше привяжи к пользователю и дате

Comment: Но регистрации, и вообще пользователей нет, нужно сделать хранение и удаление данных в сессиях, чтобы у каждого, кто заходил на сайт, были свои индивидуальные данные.

Comment: Создаешь табличку, можно без полей, можно добавить имя.. Берешь айди с этой таблички - кладешь в сессию и кладешь в м2м табличку. Всё

Comment: Как айди таблички в сессию положить?

Comment: `request.session['session_id'] = ration.id`